# Adding a linked list to another in O(1)

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Two **Singly** linked Lists, size m , r and want to insert the first linked list nodes after the head of the second linked list, and the time complexity has to be O(1) of the method.

This really an intereseting difficult problem for me. Eatch time I think of a solution, the Time complexity is O(m+r)

I need some hints to solve this. I consumed useless effort on this problem.

EDIT:

Let me share what I have so far:

1. Create a new Linked List
2. Add the HEAD of the 2nd list
3. Still O(1)
4. Add all the nodes of 1st list
5. Becomes (n)
6. Add the rest of the nodes from the 1st list
7. Becomes another (n-1)

UPDATE:

What do you think about this? I got inspired directly after I asked here :)
[image]

Comment: If you develop your own LinkedList you can do this, but not using the existing List.

Comment: Do you want to be able to use the original lists afterwards?

Comment: @JonSkeet no sir, the new linkd list only

Comment: your linked list visualization/handdrawing is wrong. this looks like an array. every element needs a pointer to the "next" element instead. cuz they  are linked... have a look, http://www.stoimen.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/0.-Arrays-vs.-linked-list.png . you can visualize and solve it after that :)

Comment: @HayatiGuvence To fast the drawing I made it to look like an array. I'll get back home and do it and will post the results. By the way, the link you shared has a a pointer to the `previous` node which it is only in `Double Linked List` so it's not the case here.

Comment: double linked list is not necessarily needed for this problem, either. if there is information as "tail" in that linked list impl, it can run O(1). just switching "next" elements. if there is no reference to "tail" node, in that case, it would be O(n) (in order to reach it by traversing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have these structures:

- List

  - Head node
  - Tail node
- Node

  - Value
  - Next node

Reminder to self: the goal is: "insert the first linked list nodes after the head of the second linked list".

Then all you've got to do is:

```
// Hook up the end of list1 to the original second element of list2
list1.tail.next = list2.head.next;
// Set the second element of list2 to be the first element of list1
list2.head.next = list1.head;
```

List2 still ends where it did before (its tail node is the same).

You've now got `list1` with a "floating" head, which is generally bad news... but if you iterate over `list1` you'll get all the elements from both original lists...

Comment: @iMohammad: I'd missed the "after the head" part - will fix that. I'm not sure what your update really adds though...

Comment: Just got back from a 3 days break. I just code it based on my rough sketch and it's correct. Regarding your solution, it uses the same idea, however, I'm not sure what do you mean by "Floating" Head?

Comment: @iMohammad: I mean that `list1` has a `head` reference which isn't really the head of a list. It's the second element of `list2`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two singly-linked lists and don't have the tail of the first already, this is only possible in O(n).  If you have the tail you simply make it point to the head of the second list...

Edit:  2nd list head points to first list's head.  Hold a reference to 2nd list's 2nd node.  Iterate down first list - again this is O(n) if you don't have a reference to the tail to start - and have the tail of that point to the original 2nd element of the 2nd list.

Comment: The problem says I have to insert all the nodes of the first right after the head of e second list.